# Restrict members of Microsoft Team to add additional members

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We want to restrict the members of the Private Team  to create\update\delete channel and to add or remove additional members to the Members

We are creating Private Microsoft Team using POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams with 'standard' template.

We can able to set the following members settings for the Team.

`'memberSettings': { 'allowCreateUpdateChannels': false, 'allowDeleteChannels': false, 'allowCreatePrivateChannels': false, 'allowAddRemoveApps': true, 'allowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs': false, 'allowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors': false },`

But it not restricting the members to 'add Members' and 'Leave the Team' i.e Members can able to add other members and they can able to leave the team.

Is there any settings available through Microsoft Teams Graph API to restrict the member options 'Add Members' and 'Leave the Team' ?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Only Owners can add people to the team which is set to private. As far as leaving the team goes there is no such option, Graph or Otherwise. You can always set to a Flow to listen on people leaving the team and automatically add them back.